# OpenGL ES 2.0 not drawing images with shadows

Tags: shaders, rendering, opengl-es, shadows, glow

I'm using OpenGL ES 2 to program a simple game 2D for Android mobile phones. I'm coding the rendering portion of the software, using the GLES20 default library.
All my sprites are rendered from a large image containing all the pictures of what I need. I use very basic fragment and vertex shaders which are the following:

**Vertex** shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
     gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
     v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
 }
```

**Fragment** shader:

```
 precision mediump float;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord;
 uniform sampler2D s_texture;
 void main() {
      vec4 dst = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord); 
      gl_FragColor = dst;

  }
```

Those are the shaders I use and everything is rendering fine.
I also set the blending function to:

```
 GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The problem is that I needed a sort of shadow around an object, so  I decided to solve this problem simply making the game image with already the shadow in it.

So, as you can see, here is a piece of my image with a large orange outside shadow so I get the effect that the main object (the two columns in the middle) is glowing.

[image]

(*Ignore the black background, I put it there to make the shadow visible, it's not there in the real game image*)

Anyway, when I render this image I get this **result**:

[image]

As you can clearly see, **there is not any sort of shadow**, even it is there in the source image.
What is really strange from my point of view is that I don't generate the shadow using the shaders, I created it in a very static (and probably not very effective) way: using Photoshop.

**How can I make the outer orange glow visible ?**

Thank you in advice